# how to get flavor specific information of HLS(cupertino) live streaming using wowza server module api

Tags: wowza

I am working on wowza live streaming analytics module for hls and rtmp streams.
i want to fetch following information from HLS and RTMP type live streaming...

- viewer's information
- viewer-end user-agent
- total data streamed to viewer
- total play duration of media
- flavours played during the stream.

i've fetched this data for RTMP live streaming using following listener and classes:

- Listener: `IMediaStream.addClientListener()`
- Notifier: `IMediaStreamActionNotify3`
- Some wowza's basic server API

i am not aware about the listener to get stream specific information in case of HLS[cupertino] live streaming.
i've achieved following in case of HLS[cupertino] live streaming:

- total data transferred to viewer
- user-agent
- viewer's information

and the information that is not achieved yet in HLS live streaming:

- total play duration of media
- flavors played during the stream

i've tried a listener `HTTPStreamerApplicationContextCupertinoStreamer.addVODActionListener()` but it works with VOD type applications only.

Can you please help me on this to achieve it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can check out the serverinfo http provider and check the protocol info in a similar way as shown [here](https://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?43017-How-to-get-HLS-live-stream-information&p=164032#post164032)